# String Array Causes C++ Program to Crash

Tags: c++, arrays, string, crash

I'm doing work on a multifunction program for my programming class, and one of the functions requires that an array of strings be used.

The objective is to store 10 names in an array, and then have the user enter a number that randomly determines the 'winning' name.

The only problem is that, once I execute my code, the program crashes after completing the 10 loops to get the names. That's the main thing I'm trying to identify, what's causing the crash.

The entire program is much larger, but the relevant code is shown below.

```
string Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6, Name7, Name8, Name9,     Name10, tempName, winName;

string array[10] = {Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6, Name7, Name8, Name9, Name10};

int tempNum = 0;
int winNum;
int userEntry;
int userSelection;

for (int test = 0; test < 11; test++)
{
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin >> tempName;

    array[tempNum] = tempName;
    tempNum++;
}

//The program crashes at this exact spot, right after collecting the 10th name

cout << endl;
cout << "Now choose a random number between 1 and 100: ";
cin >> userEntry;

winNum = static_cast<int>(userEntry * 3.14159 + 12.7 * 10) % 10;

winName = array[winNum];

cout << endl;
cout << "The winner of the game is" << winName << "!" << endl;
```

Comment: What did you observe stepping through your program line by line using the debugger?

Comment: Right after you collect the tenth name, you attempt to collect an eleventh name, did you notice?

Comment: Dereferencing `array[10`] is beyond valid bounds!

Comment: The debugger doesn't bring up any errors. The program loads without issues. It's just once it reaches the end of that loop that it crashes.

Comment: @PolarisInParis The debugger also means you have to keep your eyes peeled on your code while you're stepping through it.  You should have seen that you are trying to write to `array[10]`.  That is out of bounds.

Comment: _"The debugger doesn't bring up any errors. "_ I don't completely understand what you're trying to tell with this statement. The debugger doesn't do the job for you, to inspect your intended program logic and advise about errors you've put into it. You have to step through your code line by line, and watch how variable values change intentionally or not. Learn the basic skills first before asking here please!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Seriously another misconception of what _the debugger_ actually is.

Comment: I apologize, I mistook the runtime debugger for the starting build compiler. I will certainly keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop you are trying to access to `array[10]` and that does not exist since array has only 10 elements, from 0 to 9. That's why your program is crashing.

Change the condition in your for loop from `for (int test = 0; test < 11; test++)` to `for (int test = 0; test < 10; test++)` and it should works.

Comment: Haha, I'm both slightly embarrassed and relieved that the answer was such a trivial math error. Switching that back to 10 fixes the program, and it runs flawlessly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 10 elements and and you are accessing 11 elements, 0 to 10, which is causing your program to crash. Because your code is accessing a location which doesn't belong to your program. Change the condition in for loop from `test < 11` to `test < 10`.
Use "`at`" function of `string` class if you can, it throws an exception when you try to access out of bound subscripts.

Answer (score -1):

Two problems.

One, you're instantiating an array with 10 elements then looking up its 11th element.
Firstly, change the if condition from test < 11 to test < 10.
This will solve your crash.

Secondly, your program could crash for large inputs.
When you initialize the string array, the compiler assigns a certain amount of memory to the array.

The amount of memory allocated to array is determined by the compiler.
The compiler determines the size of each of the string variables, and multiplies it by 10 to get the total size needed by the array, and allocates that much memory accordingly.

While strings can resize dynamically, arrays do not. The array has a fixed amount of memory allocated to it.

Hence, if during input of the strings that you save into the array by overwriting its indices, you could write into the array more characters than it can hold.

The amount of memory that will be allocated is implementation dependent since the default capacity of a string is implementation dependent.

A simple workaround would be to define the name strings to a large string at the beginning like string Name1 = "-------------------------";

This way the user input is most likely smaller in size that the initial value.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, even after setting all the name values to = " ", the program still crashes at the same spot. I would consider changing the coding method away from being an array, but the assignment's instructions specifically require that an array be used there.

Comment: How does your "simple workaround" resolve the problem of accessing past the end of the array? Hint: it doesn't

Comment: Also, did you mean to iterate 10 times instead of 11? Change test < 11 to test < 10. Editting the answer given that this needs to stay an array.